# How the pop up works in the KendoUI grid and how to bring the controls in the pop up in KendoUI ajax grid for MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

How the popup window works when the edit button is click and how to bring the three Combobox in the popup. I am really confused with the below code

```
Client side Code

    //show server errors if any
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("SchoolGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.SchoolID).Width("80px");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Campus).Width("90px");
        columns.Bound(p => p.StateCode).Width("90px");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SectorCode).Width("95px");
        columns.Bound(p => p.MDISurveyStartDate).ClientTemplate("#= (MDISurveyStartDate == null) ? 'Not Set' : kendo.toString(MDISurveyStartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') #").Width("90px");
        columns.Bound(p => p.MDISurveyEndDate).ClientTemplate("#= (MDISurveyEndDate == null) ? 'Not Set' : kendo.toString(MDISurveyEndDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') #").Width("90px");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width("190px").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
    })
    .ToolBar(tb => tb.Create().Text("Add New School"))
    .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("EditSchool").Window(w => w.Title("Add/Edit School Details").Name("editWindow").Width(600)))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ClientID))
        .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read("Read_Schools", "School")
        .Update("Update", "School")
        .Create("Create", "School")
        .Destroy("Destroy", "School")
    )
)


Server Side Code:-

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, School school)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string errMsg = "";
                    if (!_Service.UpdateSchool(school, out errMsg))
                        ModelState.AddModelError("UpdateSchool", errMsg);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("UpdateSchool", ex.Message);
            }

            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is code library](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor.aspx) which shows how to manipulate the content of the Window. Rest of the editing is possible through the **edit** event of the Grid (check documentation).